# How would I call (for eg.) a function to connect to a function to search using wxPython

Tags: wxpython

Below are five functions of my program to connect to an Ubuntu server using Paramiko. I wrote a command line script in Python that handles this perfectly, but I'm attempting to learn wxPython and I'm having a few challenges. The script works fine if I have it one function, but, being a newb, I'm trying to practice to write more efficient code. As the function are, I'm getting a message that "ssh is not defined ..." I've tried passing parameters, and other combination of things ... I guess I'm overlooking something. Can someone assist me with this?

```
def OnIP(self, event):
    panel=wx.Panel(self)
    dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "Enter the IP Address.",
    'Dispenser Connect', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        ip_address = dlg.GetValue()
    if ip_address:    
        cmsg = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Do you want to connect to: ' + ip_address,
                                'Connect', wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
        result = cmsg.ShowModal()

    if result == wx.ID_YES:
        self.DispConnect(ip_address)

        cmsg.Destroy()
    dlg.Destroy()

    return True


def GoodConnect(self):
    gdcnt = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'You are connected!', 'ConnectionStatus', wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
    gdcnt.ShowModal()
    if gdcnt.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        self.OnSearch()
    gdcnt.Destroy()    


def ErrMsg(self):
    ermsg = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Invalid Entry!', 'ConnectionDialog', wx.ICON_ERROR)
    ermsg.ShowModal()
    ermsg.Destroy()



def DispConnect(self, address):
    pattern = r"\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
    port = 22
    user = 'root'
    password ='******'
    if re.match(pattern, address):
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(address,port,user,password)
        self.GoodConnect()
    else:
        self.ErrMsg()

def OnSearch(self, somevariable):  
    apath = '/'
    apattern = '"*.txt" -o -name "*.log"' 
    rawcommand = 'find {path} -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log"' #{pattern}
    command1 = rawcommand.format(path=apath, pattern=apattern)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command1)
    filelist = stdout.read().splitlines()
    ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `ssh` in `DispConnect()` but then use it again in `OnSearch()` where it hasn't been defined.  Since this is all taking place in the same class (I assume), make your last line in the `if re.match...` be

```
self.ssh = ssh
```

Then in OnSearch(), use `self.ssh` instead of `ssh`.

That is, the local variables you use within methods aren't available outside of those methods.  Using `self.ssh` makes this a member of the class, and it can then be used anywhere within the class.

Comment: You really shouldn't be getting the same error, because a class not having a particular member (following my soln) should raise an AttributeError, and a name not existing (what you originally had) should give a NameError.  Anyway, there are only two issues, the scope of a name and when it's defined, and I mentioned the solution to this above.  Beyond this, it's just debugging, which I can't do with such limited information.